# Is it possible to create universal app without separate xib except MainWindow.xib..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Since last few days i have been searching and think about universal app conversation.  I came to know that in Xcode 3.0 there is the `UIViewAutoResizingMask` property and you can convert your app into universal app with single xib.  So, if anybody know this way than please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
If you can't adjust the interface using springs and struts make device-based adjustments in code. E.g.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) /* iPad */
{
    self.someView.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
}
else /* iPhone, iPod */
{
    self.someView.center = CGPointMake(200, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that with objects such as tableview, navigation bars and tab bars etc, when in universal mode, these are automatically resized if using the same view. The only problem I might see is those objects such as buttons and the resizing it relocating of these. I myself am not sure about this, but I'm sure that there's a way of doing so in the same view.